# jMeter freezes in cloud based solution

Tags: cloud, jmeter, load-testing

Currently I am working with jmeter in the cloud.

I have a scenario to execute with 20,000 users. But after 10,000 it freezes. I checked the CPU time: it is utilizing 100%.

Please advise me what to do to avoid this situation.

1. number of users = 20000
   loop count = 1
2. can i use number of users = 10000 and loop count = 2 ?

What will be the difference between 1 & 2?

We don't have separate requirement only is execute our scripts with 20,000 users.

3: What is the max number of Thread counts are allowed in Jmeter Cloud?

Comment: Any feedback on this ? If answer was ok you should accept it so that it's helpful to others

Answer (score 0):

There is no JMeter Cloud . What exactly are you talking about ? 
If CPU is at 100% then:

Either your Test Plan is wrong, read this to check it first:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html

Your machine or set of machines is not powerful enough, you can try using Distributed testing or some Cloud based commercial solution:

- http://www.flood.io
- http://blazemeter.com/

Finally to answer your question 1 and 2 are pretty different simulations

Answer (score 0):

You are generating 20000 users load from one machine,so it would be better if you use distributed testing on cloud.You can prepare your scenarios like this:

master machine:
No of users:10000,Loop Count:1

for 2 slave machines it gets double or if you will use 3 slave machines count becomes triple(i.e 30000).

Ans of your qsns:

1)20000 users will hit the server at a time,means in one iteration.
2)10000 users will hit the server in one iteration and after that 10000 will enter in 2nd iteration.

I guess distributed testing will help you to reduce the CPU utilization.Because it reduces the load generated from one machine.

Answer (score 0):

**You should remove all listeners**

- View Results in Table
- View Results in Tree
- Graph Results
- Assertion Results
- Distribution Graph
- Graph Results

**Use non-gui for load testing.**

```
./jmeter -t testplan.jmx -n -l results.csv
```

**Use CVS as output results**

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv
jmeter.save.saveservice.data_type=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.label=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.successful=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.time=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertions=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.latency=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.hostname=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.sample_count=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=HH:mm:ss
jmeter.save.saveservice.default_delimiter=;
jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=true
```